# How do I fetch get request results one by one in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm using UnityWebRequest to fetch a JSON array of search results from an API. Instead of yielding until the whole array is returned, can I make it so that my code deals with the results one by one?

Any directions are appreciated.

Here's some code:

```c#
public IEnumerator GetMovies(string q)
{
    string uri = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=__&s=" + q;
    using (UnityWebRequest r = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        yield return r.SendWebRequest();

        if(r.isHttpError || r.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(r.error);
        }
        else
        {
            SearchInfo info = JsonUtility.FromJson<SearchInfo>(r.downloadHandler.text);

            if(info != null)
            {

                gameObject.GetComponent<EventManager>().onSearchInfoGet(info);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show us that code you are talking about?

Comment: It's pretty standard but I added some code to the post
(removed API key of course)
I'm just looking for directions on how to do it in Unity. Not actual code(necessarily).

Comment: I don't see you `yielding until the whole array is returned` ... you `yield` until your HTTP request is responded. Then you are using one `JsonUtility.FromJson` call to as I guess deserialize the json data into an array wrapper. It will be pretty hard to do some magic string operations in order to extract the individual array elements before deserializing ... How complex is your JSON structure?

Comment: in the end btw you can make it slightly more efficient if you do `GetComponent<EventManager>()` already in `Awake` and store the reference and then later only use it

Comment: Oh, I see. Can I use that to stream the content of my array one by one then? 
The structure is just a JSON object that contains the search result, each result is an object that contains information like the name, genre, and other string info about the movie.
I'm deserializing them using a class (SearchInfo) that stores an array of a class called MovieInfo, that class contains strings for these information. 
Thing is, I want to be able to load them one by one as they come in and de-serialize them. I could be receiving a lot of MovieInfo objects, don't want to wait for them to be all loaded.

Comment: as I can't use the API .. could you post an example how the JSON looks like and maybe your `SearchInfo` implementation with according types

Comment: Sure, 
implementation:
`[System.Serializable]
public class SearchInfo 
{
    public MovieSearchInfo[] Search;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MovieSearchInfo
{
    public string Title, Year, imdbID, Type;
}`

Comment: returned JSON with two results:
`Search
=0 
==Title "Tears of the Sun"
==Year "2003"
==imdbID "tt0314353"
==Type "movie"

=1 
==Title "Empire of the Sun"
==Year "1987"
==imdbID "tt0092965"
==Type "movie"`

Comment: You know that this doesn't look like a valid JSON structure? ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Put it on a thread

[`JsonUtility.FromJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

> The versions of this method that take strings can be called from background threads.

So you could try and simply do something like

```c#
// A thread save queue
ConcurrentQueue<SearchInfo> callbacks = new ConcurrentQueue<SearchInfo>();

public IEnumerator GetMovies(string q)
{
    var uri = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=__&s=" + q;
    using (var r = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        yield return r.SendWebRequest();

        if (r.isHttpError || r.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(r.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // start the deserialization task in a background thread
            // and pass in the returned string
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DeserializeAsync));
            thread.Start(r.downloadHandler.text);

            // wait until the thread writes a result to the queue
            yield return new WaitUntil(()=> !callbacks.IsEmpty);

            // read the first entry in the queue and remove it at the same time
            if (callbacks.TryDequeue(out var result))
            {
                GetComponent<EventManager>().onSearchInfoGet(result);
            }
        }
    }
}

// This happens in a background thread!
private void DeserializeAsync(object json)
{
    // now it shouldn't matter how long this takes
    var info = JsonUtility.FromJson<SearchInfo>((string)json);

    // dispatch the result back to the main thread
    callbacks.Enqueue(info);
}
```

Maybe there are more efficient ways for dispatching a single data event back to the main thread then a queue ... but at least I can say the [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.comdotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) is thread save ;)

---

#### Alternative (Maybe)

Instead of using `JsonUtility` you could use e.g. [`SimpleJSON`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) you only need to create a c# script with the content of [`SimpleJSON.cs`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON#SimpleJSON.cs) somewhere in your `Assets`.

assuming a JSON like

```json
{
    "Search" : [
        {
           "Title":"AB",
           "Year":"1999",
           "imdbID":"abcdefg",
           "Type":"AB"
        },
        {
           "Title":"IJ",
           "Year":"2000",
           "imdbID":"abcdefg",
           "Type":"IJ"
        },
        {
           "Title":"XY",
           "Year":"2001",
           "imdbID":"abcdefg",
           "Type":"XY"
        }
    ]
}
```

and your `SearchInfo` like

```c#
// This you might not need anymore
[System.Serializable] 
public class SearchInfo 
{ 
    public MovieSearchInfo[] Search; 
} 

[System.Serializable] 
public class MovieSearchInfo 
{ 
    public string Title; 
    public string Year; 
    public string imdbID;
    public string Type; 
}
```

Then you could use it in order to parse the classes "manualy" like e.g.

```c#
// Give your IEnumerator a callback parameter
public IEnumerator GetMovies(string q, Action<JSONArray> OnSuccess = null)
{
    var uri = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=__&s=" + q;
    using (var r = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        yield return r.SendWebRequest();

        if (r.isHttpError || r.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(r.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not sure though if this call is faster then
            // simply using JsonUtility ...
            var N = JSON.Parse(r.downloadHandler.text);

            var theJsonArray = N["Search"].Values;

            // Now depending on what you actually mean by one-by-one
            // you could e.g. handle only one MoveInfo per frame like
            foreach (var item in theJsonArray)
            {
                var movieInfo = new MovieSearchInfo();
                movieInfo.Title = item["title"];
                movieInfo.Year = item["Year"];
                movieInfo.imdbID = item["imdbID"];
                movieInfo.Type = item["Type"];

                // NOW DO SOMETHING WITH IT

                // wait for the next frame to continue
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Otherwise you could also checkout [other JSON libraries](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil#serialization).